# Moving Average Lengths that Change Depending on Timeframe

Tags: pine-script

I'd like to modify Tradingview's moving average ribbon indicator to automatically switch between different moving averages depending on the timeframe. For low timeframes <= 5m I like to use 60, 120 and 180-period moving averages which equates to 1, 2, 3 hours in the case of the 1m timeframe, while for higher timeframes I like to use 50, 100 and 200-period moving averages as they are the most followed averages by other traders.

In the code below I'd like to automate the indicator to plot ma3Scalp (60 period) when using a timeframe 5 minutes or under and switch to ma3Swing (50 period) when using all higher timeframes. I've tried using timeframe.multiplier and timeframe.period but with no luck. Basically I want "if (timeframe <=5m) plot Scalp, else plot Swing.

```
show_ma3   = input(true   , "MA №3", inline="MA #3")
ma3_type   = input.string("EMA"  , ""     , inline="MA #3", options=["SMA", "EMA", "SMMA (RMA)", "WMA", "VWMA"])
ma3_source = input(close  , ""     , inline="MA #3")
ma3Scalp_length = input.int(60    , "Scalp"     , minval=1)
ma3Swing_length = input.int(50    , "Swing"     ,  minval=1)
ma3_color  = input(color.new(#4caf50, 40), ""     , inline="MA #3")
ma3Scalp = ma(ma3_source, ma3Scalp_length, ma3_type)
ma3Swing = ma(ma3_source, ma3Swing_length, ma3_type)
plot(show_ma3 ? ma3Scalp : na, color = ma3_color, title="MA №3")
plot(show_ma3 ? ma3Swing : na, color = ma3_color, title="MA №3")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for you so you can use multiple conditions and timeframes in your code.

The idea is converting chart's timeframe into minutes and using that to set your length.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script", overlay=true)

f_resInMinutes() => 
    _resInMinutes = timeframe.multiplier * (
      timeframe.isseconds ? 1. / 60             :
      timeframe.isminutes ? 1.                  :
      timeframe.isdaily   ? 60. * 24            :
      timeframe.isweekly  ? 60. * 24 * 7        :
      timeframe.ismonthly ? 60. * 24 * 30.4375  : na)

f_getLen(t) =>
    l = 0
    if (t >= 120)      // 2h and above
        l := 100
    else if (t >= 60)  // 1h and above
        l := 50
    else if (t >= 15)  // 15min and above
        l := 25
    else
        l := 5

t_in_min = f_resInMinutes()
len = f_getLen(t_in_min)

_ema = ta.ema(close, len)

plot(_ema, color=color.yellow)
```

Comment: How can you use only the slice values in `close` that are from that day? As in, resetting for example `ta.ema` or `ta.sma` to start at the beginning of 7:00AM for premarket session or 9:30 AM for regular market session?

Comment: @BrandonRos, you can calculate the number of bars from 7:00AM to current bar and use that as `length`.